# Test if a Type is an Attribute?

Tags: c#, attributes

I got the following code the works :

```
var library = Assembly.LoadFrom(libraryPath);

var namespaces = library.GetTypes().GroupBy(t => t.Namespace);
foreach (var typesInNamespace in namespaces)
{
    foreach (var type in typesInNamespace)
    {
        [...]
    }
}
```

But when I want to test if the current Type is an Attribute with this code :

```
var attributes = typesInNamespace.Where(t => t is System.Attribute);
```

or

```
if (type is System.Attribute)
```

they both fail and I have the following warning :

```
The given expression is never of the provided ('System.Attribute') type
```

The classes are defined like this :

```
class ImportableModelAttribute : Attribute
{
}

class ImportableAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

To be honest, I was expecting a sort of API to deal with Attributes (something like `if (type.IsAtteribute)`) but I didnt find anything, that's why I'm trying to do it this way !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `Type` itself is never an attribute (in the same way that `typeof(string)` isn't a string), but I suspect you want:

```
if (typeof(Attribute).IsAssignableFrom(type))
```

(Or put that in a lambda experssion, of course.)

See the docs for [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx) for more information.

Comment: It's 9am here in France, I need a coffee -_-
Thx anyway !

Comment: @JonSkeet And, is `type.IsSubClassOf(typeof(Attribute))` valid in this scenario too? In fact, you know that "some is of some type" because it's the type or inherits it.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: Yes, that would do fine - I tend to use `IsAssignableFrom` by default as I usually want to include the type itself, but in this case it wouldn't be an issue.